# Why Do B+ Trees Have a Minimum Occupancy of 50%?

Tags: algorithms, database, data-structures

As far as I can tell, the basic operations (add, delete, search) on a B+ Tree would function the same if minimum occupancy was 1, or 1/3, or any other function on node size.

All the sources available give the minimum occupancy as 50%.  Why 50%?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Minimum occupancies of greater than 50% don't work, because when you need to split a node because the node is too full, it would be impossible to cut a node such that the two resulting nodes were greater than 50% full. (You could do 60/40 or something like that but the smaller node would always fail the data structure's invariant of each node being greater than 60% full, for example)

Minimum occupancies of less than 50% waste space because the goal is to need to read in the fewest number of nodes from secondary storage / memory, and increasing the amount of empty space in each node means that the average request needs to read a greater number of nodes from disk. (It would also be tricky to implement effectively given that the split operation needs to split into 1/(ratio) chunks instead of 2 chunks)

Answer (score 3):

A minimum occupancy of 1 isn't possible with a B+ tree as each node has to have one entry from the parent node.

Occupancies of less than 50% means that the tree can be made more efficient by redistributing entries between nodes and if two nodes have less than 50% occupancy, they get merged into one node. Or as Billy ONeal points out, the tree grows by splitting nodes, to have less than 50% occupancy, you would need to split one node into 3 or more.

Comment: can you touch on your first point a little more?  i thought the branching factor was the node size + 1, so there isn't a one-to-one mapping of child nodes to parent entries.  i was imagining a B+ tree with a minimum occupancy of one would just look like a BST.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree The leaf nodes have an extra link to form a linked list which can be read sequentially from leaf to leaf.